# Get two fileds from Array result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

My service give result as follows

```
$scope.ListOfPeople = [
    { PersonID: 10, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Smith", Sex: "Male" },
    { PersonID: 11, FirstName: "James", LastName: "Last", Sex: "Male" },
    { PersonID: 12, FirstName: "Mary", LastName: "Heart", Sex: "Female" },
    { PersonID: 13, FirstName: "Sandra", LastName: "Goldsmith", Sex: "Female" },
    { PersonID: 14, FirstName: "Shaun", LastName: "Sheep", Sex: "Male" },
    { PersonID: 15, FirstName: "Nicola", LastName: "Smith", Sex: "Male" }
];
```

I need to customise my datasource as follows

```
$scope.output= [
    { PersonID: 10, FirstName: "John" },
    { PersonID: 11, FirstName: "James" },
    { PersonID: 12, FirstName: "Mary" },
    { PersonID: 13, FirstName: "Sandra" },
    { PersonID: 14, FirstName: "Shaun" },
    { PersonID: 15, FirstName: "Nicola" }
];
```

What is the best way to do this in angularjs

Comment: look at [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to achieve your goal. Take in account that the `map` creates new array.

```
$scope.output = $scope.ListOfPeople.map(function(item){
    return {
        PersonID: item.PersonID,
        FirstName: item.FirstName
    };
});
```

Comment: Take in account that you could need Polyfill as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create a new array to reshape it's elements. Just delete unwanted properties  from your elements.

```
//Iterate through the array
$scope.listOfPeople.forEach(function(obj){

    //Iterate through properties
    for (var property in obj) {
       if (['PersonId', 'FirstName'].indexOf(property) < 0)     //Delete anything you don't name here
          delete obj[property]; 
   }      

})
```